# CodeIgniter - Creating a new page, getting a 404 message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a new page that will bring up a form for them to enter a name for a group. It will then create the group and add them as a member to it. I have a similar sign up that I have copied and changed to fit the needs of this, but when I try to access it it gives me a 404 message.

I am accessing the controller (groups.php):

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

function index() {
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('group_view');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');

    $this->createGroup();
}
function createGroup() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    // validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { //didnt validate

        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('group_view');
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    } else {
        $this->load->model('model_groups');

        if($query = $this->model_groups->createGroup()) {

            //$data['account_created'] = 'Your account has been created.<br/><br/>You may now sign in.';

            $this->load->view('includes/header');
            $this->load->view('home_view');
            $this->load->view('includes/footer');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('includes/header');
            $this->load->view('group_view');
            $this->load->view('includes/footer');
        }
    } 

}
}
?>
```

I can post the model and view if necessary but Im pretty sure the problem is in the controller as that is what I am trying to load. Please let me know as soon as possible what my problem is! Thanks guys!

Comment: Your class name is `Login`, is it correct?

Comment: Wow, sometimes it just needs a second pair of eyes xD I cant believe I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your class name `Login` to `Group`